# How to switch place of two columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, multiple-columns

i was trying to implement a three column website using bootstrap and there is

```
[left-sidebar] [main-content] [right-sidebar]
```

when this layout is viewed in mobile view it becomes like this

```
[left-sidebar] 
[main-content] 
[right-sidebar]
```

so i want to switch the place of the `[main-content]` with the `[left-sidebar]`

```
[main-content]
[left-sidebar]  
[right-sidebar]
```

here is the code i have used

```
<div class  = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-3">
        [left-sidebar]
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-6">
        [main-content]
    </div>
    <div class = "col-md-3">
        [right-sidebar]
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
        [main-sidebar]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">
        [left-content]
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        [right-sidebar]
    </div>
</div>
```